# How can I use mongodump to dump out records matching a specific date range?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use the mongodump command to dump out a bunch of records created on a specific date. The records include a "ts" field which is a MongoDB Date() object.

mongodump takes a -q argument which can be used to run a query to select the records to be included in the dump. Unfortunately, the -q argument needs to be provided in JSON, and it's not clear how to express a "less-than-this-date, more-than-this-date" query in pure JSON (normally such queries would use a 'new Date()' constructor)"

Any tips? I've tried using the {$date: unix-timestamp-in-milliseconds} format but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 78):

I solved it - the magic incantation I was looking for is:

```
mongodump --query "{\"ts\":{\"\$gt\":{\"\$date\":`date -d 2011-08-10 +%s`000},\"\$lte\":{\"\$date\":`date -d 2011-08-11 +%s`000}}}"
```

Comment: don't be afraid to accept this as the answer, worked for me - didn't realize I had to escape the dollar signs.

Comment: is there documentation somewhere for the date-in-JSON format you're using here?  what is `\`date -d 2011-08-10 +%s\`000` all about?

Comment: @ericsoco looks like he's running a shell command to generate the date

Comment: Worked for me too. It may not be as human readable as other solutions, but the date part it's the most human readable part compare to 13-digit number that you should make it every time! Thanks Simon.

Comment: He is running the shell command to convert the date to a unix timestamp and then appending `000` to make it milliseconds.

Comment: You can escape the json by wrapping it in single quotes.

Answer (score 32):

A more human-readable version than @SimonWillison's escaped version:

`--query "{ time: { \$gt: new Date(1312959600000), \$lt: new Date(1313046000000) }}"`

(Note the dollarsigns still need to be escaped.)

I got the millisecond timestamps by creating dates in the shell, e.g.:

```
> var targetDateStart = new Date(2011, 7, 10);
> var targetDateEnd = new Date(2011, 7, 11);
> targetDateStart.getTime();
1312959600000
> targetDateEnd.getTime();
1313046000000
```

Comment: `$` is not needed to be escaped if you use single quote `'`. In fact this is recommended way, `'{ time: { $gt: new Date(1312959600000), $lt: new Date(1313046000000) }}'`

Answer (score 31):

In MongoDB 3.2, we can use `--queryFile` option with mongodump.

first of all, create a json file:

```
//query.json
{"serverTime": {"$gte": ISODate("2016-01-30T16:00:00.000Z"), "$lt": ISODate("2016-01-31T16:00:00.000Z")}}
```

next,use mongodump:

```
mongodump --db <dbName> --collection <collectionName> --queryFile query.json
```

simple and clear.

Comment: I've the same issue, need to use new Date instead of ISODate

//query.json
{"serverTime": {"$gte":  new Date("2016-01-30T16:00:00.000Z"), "$lt": new Date("2016-01-31T16:00:00.000Z")}}

Answer (score 11):

Edit: fixed typos

Add an update:

1. `mongodump --query` doesn't support `IsoDate`, but accepts `Date` in milliseconds form.
2. As `date` command behaves different in OS X, `date -d 2011-08-10 +%s` does not work for me. If you've run into the same issue, try to read the manual or use this:

   - Get current time in seconds:

     ```
     date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s"
     ```
   - Get specific time in seconds:

     ```
     date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2014-01-01 00:00:00"  "+%s"
     ```
3. Use the single quote version to avoid escaping.

   ```
   mongodump --query '{updated_at: { $gte: Date(1403280000000) } }'
   ```

Comment: First command `Failed conversion of \`\`Mar 15 sep 2015 10:49:19 CEST'' using format \`\`%a %b %d %T %Z %Y''` Second command gives me the same as javascripts `Date.UTC(...) / 1000` but differs from `ISODate(...).getTime() / 1000` (by 2 hours because I'm in France)

Comment: It lacks a bracket. The correct syntax is:

`mongodump --query '{updated_at: { $gte: Date(1403280000000) } }'`

Answer (score 6):

This should work, what didn't work about your $date query? :

```
mongodump --query  {"ts":{$gt:{$date:178929000}}}
```

Comment: Mongo shell won't recognize the `$date` operator , so you need to use `Date()` or `ISODate()`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26227744/404699

Answer (score 5):

use single quotes around the query.  I found that ISODate() doesn't work.

```
mongodump --query  '{"ts":{$gt:{$date:178929000}}}'
```

Comment: Single quotes are indeed essential (surprisingly), thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Extended JSON Format works, as can be found in the documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/). Example:

`--query '{ "timest": { "$gte": { "$date": "2020-08-19T00:00:00.000Z" } } }'`

Answer (score 1):

In `mongodump` version 100, I couldn't get the previous solutions to work.

This is one solution that worked for me:

- Get the unix epoch for the datetime that you want to get the records after. The simplest way could be to run `new Date(<your date>).getTime()` in your browser console or a Javascript REPL.

Example: `new Date('2022-07-01').getTime()` -> `1656633600000`

- Create a json queryfile, eg. `queryFile.json`:

```
{
  "updatedAt": {
    "$gt": { "$date": 165662640000 }
  }
}
```

- Run `mongodump` by specifying the `queryFile` parameter using the following command:

```
mongodump --db <dbName> --collection <collectionName> --queryFile queryFile.json
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I queried entries created 14 days ago and end up with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
date_now=`date +%s%3N`
date_2weeks_ago=$[date_now - 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000]
query=$(printf '{ createdAt: { $gte: Date(%d) } }' $date_2weeks_ago)
echo $query > query.json
mongodump \
--collection=data \
--queryFile=query.json
rm query.json
```

mongodump version: r4.0.12